# How to fetch pins of an user by their username using Pinterest JavaScript API

Tags: pinterest, pins

Pinterest API is so ugly, help me to fetch user pins,boards etc

Comment: What's ugly about it? Its a standard REST API. Also, you can only fetch the Pins of the currently authenticated user.

Comment: I did it without authenticating an user.

Comment: Yup its possible. Just not technically legal to use the widget API. So don't use it for production work.