# API to get another user's info?

Tags: web-services, pinterest

I went through the Pinterest's developer center and also found [a thread from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543325/how-to-fetch-pins-of-an-user-by-their-username-using-pinterest-javascript-api) which mentions that getting another Pinterest user's info (pins, follower count, etc.) is not part of the API. Is that correct? Can someone please confirm.

I also found mentions of *V3* Pinterest API, but can't find official documentation for it. How can I get access to the V3 API?

Comment: did you try to even google this?  google: pinterest api, it's the first result.

Comment: @KyleB - Thanks for trying to help with the question. Google's first result for Pinterest API shows their developer center. As I mentioned, I've already gone through it and didn't find the answer.

Their dev center shows the users endpoint /v1/me/* all of these gives info on the authenticated user, but not any other user. I'm looking for something like /v1/<username>/* I've already tried substituting 'me' for usernames, but none of them work. Do you get a different result on Google search?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything about v3 of the API on their documentation.

But as with most APIs like Pinterest's API, you can only get the user information *for the currently authenticated user*, not just random users.  When they log in using OAuth, they will get a prompt for permission like this image:

[image: This application would like your permission. Access your profile info, Access your followers, etc.]

So, if your `user` allows `your app` to have those permissions you should be able to access the [user object](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/users/) which includes a `counts` property.  According to the docs, the `counts` property includes: "The user’s stats, including how many Pins, follows, boards they have".